# Not Getting External Font in Android

Tags: android, fonts

I am not getting external font, from creating new class, where i defined external font.

**FontStyle.Java**

```
public class FontStyle extends Activity{
    public final static String roboto_regular = "fonts/roboto_regular.ttf";
    public Typeface font_roboto_regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
        roboto_regular);

}
```

and **MainActivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
FontStyle font_style;
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
            fontStyling();
    }

   private void fontStyling() {
   TextView test= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_test);
   test.setTypeface(font_style.font_roboto_regular );
}
```

I am getting this error or logcat:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

please guy correct me: thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you will need to pass Activity context in `FontStyle` to access `getAssets` method. if FontStyle is not an Activity then no need to extends Activity to it. change your FontStyle class as:

```
public class FontStyle {
Context context;
public final static String roboto_regular = "fonts/roboto_regular.ttf";
public FontStyle(Context context){
 this.context=context;
}
  public Typeface getTtypeface(){
     Typeface font_roboto_regular = 
        Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),roboto_regular);

    return font_roboto_regular;
  }
}
```

Now change Activity code as to set Custom font for TextView :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
FontStyle font_style;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        font_style=new FontStyle(MainActivity.this);
        fontStyling();
    }

private void fontStyling() {
TextView test= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_test);
test.setTypeface(font_style.getTtypeface());
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so Much...getting solve issues... but i have 2 fonts so how to get in three different text view. Its ok, I make three different function like getRegularTypeface()) and getBoldTypeface().